# How do you setup the convert extension in Mercurial in windows?

Tags: mercurial

I have just installed mercurial (command line only...this is not TortoiseHG) onto a Windows SErver 2003 machine and the documentation mentions a convert command that will allow me convert an svn repo to hg.

But when I try to run hg convert the command is not recognized.  I googled it and it says that I need to install the "convert extension" using the hgrc file.

I HAVE google this and I cannot find anything that will tell me EXACTLY how to get it working.  I don't know what file and filename is needed and which directory path should it be in.

I found [this page](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html) which talks generically about configuration and [this page](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension) which talks about the convert extension but neither of them puts it together with enough specificity.

SUMMARY- exactly how do I setup hg to support the convert extension on Windows Server 2003.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If your user name on the machine is "seth", and your profile is located at "c:\users\seth":

Place a file called Mercurial.ini in that folder.

Put this in the file:

```
[extensions]
hgext.convert=
```

That should at least get it to where the command is recognized and you might be able to take it from there.

EDIT:

One more thing thats not exactly clear from your post. If typing just plain `hg` does nothing then you need to put the mercurial install directory in your path.

Comment: Now convert is working.  Now I am getting error "Subversion python bindings could not be loaded."  I found an so error with that message but I am clueless on how to solve.

Comment: If you put Mercurial.ini in the install directory it should be there for everyone. Sorry, can't help with the subversion python bindings.